# Switch editable DataGridCells to edit mode when row was selected?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-style

My overall user interaction goal is to clearly and visually inform the users which datagridcell fields are available for editing, and which are not.

The below style almost works (the DataGridCells on the DataGridRow gets triggered with IsSelected when the row was selected by the user), but there is a wpf exception thrown if the cell (a textbox for example) is bound to a readonly property. That is, it seems that for setting IsEditing=True to work the bound property needs to be writeable.

The low-level exception is: System.InvalidOperationException: 'A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property...

My hope is that it could be possible to check, in the MultiTrigger, if the DataGridCell is bound to a writable property, but my data binding understanding is not deep enough.

```
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            <!--<Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>-->
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
``
```

Comment: Any comments about other solutions or best practices appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might get you started in the right direction.
https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/multi-triggers-multitrigger-multidatatrigger/

Can you clarify more of What exactly are you trying to accomplish with IsSelected and IsEditing?
I came up with this example to show you how to disable a text box if the corresponding bound object has "ReadOnly" set to true as per your stated goal. This would clearly show what cells can be edited.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="textBoxGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"
                                     IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnly}">
                                <TextBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                                Value="True" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ReadOnly}"
                                                         Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                                        Value="False" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBox.Style>
                            </TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like an application wide change override of the default datagrid style so that if you click on a row in the datagrid all writable bounded fields to go into edit mode by setting IsEditing=True. My trigger at the top does all that, besides the exception thrown on readonly bindings.  That is why I wonder if there is workaround for that exception throwing.   Sorry my wpf is not good enough.

Comment: Why do you want to tell the DataGrid to explicitly activate editing mode on all cells, when the user presumably can only edit one at a time? My suggestion would be to let the built-in editing events take place naturally and control what cannot be edited by values stored in your data. Regardless, I think the link I posted in my answer will still help you apply triggers to your app style template.

Comment: I agree that one should not try to adjust or break away very much from the natural edit flow, in any windows control. So, it was a bad idea from the very beginning that I put forward under time pressure.